# Fragment is restored but then recreated on screen orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-orientation, fragmentmanager

I have an Activity (`MainActivity`) with a DrawerLayout using a `NavigationDrawerFragment` as a navigation menu. In this `NavigationDrawerFragment`, on navigation item click, `startActivity(intent to MainActivity with extra)` is called to send an intent, received in `onNewIntent`, to `MainActivity` ; `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest ; to display the corresponding fragment. In onCreate, if saveInstanceState is not null, no fragment transaction is made because the current fragment will be automatically restored.

The problem is : for one fragment (not the others) : `DashboardFragment`, the one launched by default, on screen orientation, the fragment is restored but then recreated.

I can see that using the debugger : the regular process is called : Activity recreated, fragment restored correctly, then fragment recreated.
I can also see it in the FragmentManager logs (comparing behavior with another fragment) : the fragment is restored correctly but then, I can see a commit replacing the fragment with a new instance of `DashboardFragment`. In the code, I can't see where this commit would come from (I've put breakpoints in all the commits int the code and none is called).

Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

I can put code on request, this is a complex app, not open source, and I'm not sure which part to put here.

Simplified MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends MeerkatActivity {

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MeerkatApplication.get(this).getAppComponent().inject(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity_layout_withdrawer);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    navigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigationMenu);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
        toolbar,
        R.string.open_drawer,
        R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(R.color.primaryDarkColor);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
    //first calling before onNewIntent :
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      openFirstOpenableSection();
    }
    if (paneContainer != null) {
      // Enable animation
      LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
      transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
      paneContainer.setLayoutTransition(transition);
    }
  }

  private void openFirstOpenableSection() {
    int dc_id = -1;
    if(getIntent() != null){
      dc_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_DATACENTER_ID,-1);
    }
    int sectionToOpen = findFirstOpenableSection(sessionInformations
            .getOrganizationInformations());
    eventBus.post(new NavigationChangedEvent(sectionToOpen));
    switch (sectionToOpen) {
      case R.id.dashboard:
        if(dc_id != -1){
          IntentStarter.showDashAfterRequest(this,dc_id);
        }else{
          IntentStarter.showDashboard(this);
        }
        break;
        ...
      default:
        IntentStarter.showNoSectionAvailable(this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      String showAction = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION);
        if (rightPane != null) {
          rightPane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        switch (extras.getInt(EXTRA_MENU_ITEM, -1)) {
          case EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_DASHBOARD:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                      .replace(R.id.container, DashboardFragmentBuilder
                              .newDashboardFragment(sessionInformations.getUser().getId(),
                                      getResources().getString(R.string.dashboard_personalDashboard),
                                      "pda"), "DASHBOARD")
                      .commit();
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
            ...
          case EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
            logout();
            break;
          default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

IntentStarter :

```
public final class IntentStarter {
  public static void showDashboard(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MENU_ITEM, MainActivity.EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_DASHBOARD);
    context.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment :

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends MeerkatFragment {

      @OnClick({R.id.dashboard, ... R.id.logout})
  public void onMenuItemSelected(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.dashboard:
        desactivateAllViews();
        IntentStarter.showDashboard(getActivity());
        view.setActivated(true);
        break;
      case R.id.logout:
        IntentStarter.logout(getActivity());
        view.setActivated(true);
        break;
        ...
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you have to add some code.

Comment: have you try my answer below?

Comment: Why are you calling `startActivity()` to start the hosting `Activity` from a child `Fragment`? You can use callbacks - this is simple navigation all within the same `Activity` with multiple child `Fragments`?  If so you never need to call `startActivity` Also your comment : `I can put code on request, this is a complex app,` - we only need the RELEVANT code.

Comment: I added code. You can find the code of the DashboardFragment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364207/mvpviewstatefragment-not-restoring-viewstate-on-screen-orientation/42387169).

Comment: @MarkKeen About that, I didn't develop this app. But I don't see why this would cause my problem. I'll try to do the navigation otherwise.